# How is it possible that when I pass a lambda expression as a parameter it can access other variables in this scope?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, interface, functional-interface

```
public class ArraysDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          int[] a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
          int[] b = {10, 12, 14, 16, 18};
          Arrays.setAll(a, i -> b[i]+1);
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }  
}
```

outputs: `[11, 13, 15, 17, 19]`

The source of the `setAll()` function used is as follows:

```
public static void setAll(int[] array, IntUnaryOperator generator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(generator);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = generator.applyAsInt(i);
}
```

`IntUnaryOperator` is a functional interface and this is a part of its source:

```
public interface IntUnaryOperator {
    int applyAsInt(int operand);
    // rest methods are omitted
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding of lambda expressions in Java is that when I pass a lambda expression as a parameter to the `setAll()` method, an object of an anonymous class that implements the `IntUnaryOperator` interface is created and is called `generator`. And the lambda expression is essentially an implementation of the `applyAsInt()` method so I believe it would translate to something like:

```
int applyAsInt(int operand){
    return b[operand]+1;
}
```

It makes sense to me that it can access `operand` as it is passed as an argument in `array[i] = generator.applyAsInt(i);` However, I don't get how it can manipulate `b` - it is not passed as a parameter so how is it possible that it can be referenced? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without lambda expressions, e.g. using anonymous inner classes, you can *capture* values of the surrounding context, i.e.

```
int[] a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
int[] b = {10, 12, 14, 16, 18};
Arrays.setAll(a, new IntUnaryOperator() {
    public int applyAsInt(int i) {
        return b[i]+1;
    }
});
```

but there are some differences, though not relevant to your question. When using an anonymous inner class, the keywords `this` and `super` refer to the instance of the inner class, whereas in lambda expressions, they have the same meaning as in the surrounding context. Further, when the inner class accesses `private` members of the surrounding class, the compiler will insert helper method to perform the access, whereas lambda expressions can access the members of theur containing class naturally.

To achieve this, the code of your lambda expression `i -> b[i]+1` will get compiled to synthetic method of *your* class having the form:

```
private static int lambda$main$0(int[] b, int i) {
    return b[i]+1;
}
```

and since it’s a method within your class, it has access to all members.

So the class generated at runtime is equivalent to

```
final class ArraysDemo$Lambda$1 implements IntUnaryOperator {
    final int[] b;
    ArraysDemo$Lambda$1(int[] b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public int applyAsInt(int i) {
        return ArraysDemo.lambda$main$0(b, i);
    }
}
```

the focus on the word *equivalent*, not suggesting that it has to be exactly like this (not to speak of the fact, that ordinary Java classes couldn’t access the `private` method `ArraysDemo.lambda$main$0`).

---

But these are only technical details, the most important key point is that lambda expressions can access *effectively final* local variables as well as members of their containing class and the compiler and runtime environment will ensure that it works. You can simply consider them *functions* being evaluated in the context where they are defined.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `b` is **effectively final**.

> Instance and static variables may be used and changed without
>   restriction in the body of a lambda. The use of local variables,
>   however, is more restricted: capture of local variables is not allowed
>   unless they are effectively final, a concept introduced in Java 8.
>   Informally, a local variable is effectively final if its initial value
>   is never changed (including within the body of a lambda expression)—in
>   other words, declaring it final would not cause a compilation failure.
>   The concept of effective finality does not introduce any new semantics
>   to Java; it is simply a slightly less verbose way of defining final
>   variables.

From http://www.lambdafaq.org/can-lambda-expressions-use-variables-from-their-environment/

Answer (score 2):

```
      Arrays.setAll(a, i -> b[i]+1);
```

is equivalent to the effect of:

```
      Arrays.setAll(a, new IntUnaryOperator() {

              private int[] b$ = b;

              @Override
              public int applyAsInt(int i);
                  return b$[i]+1;
              }
          });
```

That is a variable `b` with the same name and value as the original `b` will be kept. This copy is needed as the original variable (or the new one) can have a more limited life than the other. For instance being a local variable.

To hide that there are now two variables, it is requested that they are no longer assigned to ("effectively final"), which would have lead to different values for the "same" variable.

Comment: That’s a misleading translation. Your inner class variant has to capture `b` to be able to assign it to `b$`, so you are trying to explain capturing with capturing.

Comment: @Holger that is good to point out. Would you have preferred a constructor with parameter passing? In retrospect jvm bytecode should have been added. With your reps, do you think the answer is inadequate?

Comment: Adding a constructor requires to turn it into a named class. Besides that, I would avoid writing “will become”; it’s better to say something along “will be equivalent to”. Whether the answer is adequate is hard to say, as it’s not quite clear what the OP is missing. You can explain the language-level term “*capturing*” or how it will be compiled (in terms of equivalent code, if you like) or both…